# Manage Jenkins users roles using external database

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, privileges

I'm looking for another way to manage users roles in Jenkins. Until now I'm using [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) but it's highly inconvinient solution having many roles and users: priviliges table turned into one giant indecipherable matrix.
Is there any way to connect this plugin to an external SQL db, where I could store users and their privileges and change them using queries? Or mabye somehow turning it into DSL job is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use the [Active Directory](https://plugins.jenkins.io/active-directory) plugin to manage users and roles.

Jenkins stores its information in xml files.

AFAIA, Jenkins doesn't have any plugins to integrate with databases.